# Not Displaying Image with Carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I was looking for a way to just upload photos to a database and displaying photos on a page.  I am trying carrierwave.  It uploads the photo correctly, I think, but when it goes to display the image all it does is give the location (url) of it.

Here is the uploader

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :image, :title
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
end
```

Here is the form used to upload the file

```
<%= form_for @image, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
  <% if @image.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@image.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this image from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @image.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :image %><br />
    <%= f.file_field :image %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

This is to display the image

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
  <b>Image:</b>
  <%= @image.image_url.to_s %>
</p>

<p>
  <b>Title:</b>
  <%= @image.title %>
</p>


<%= link_to 'Back', images_path %>
```

This is what prints out:

Image: /uploads/image/image/2/946612_524939910875157_1455921715_n.jpg

Title: poster

Comment: change `<%= @image.image_url.to_s %>` to  `<%= image_tag @image.image_url.to_s %>`

Answer (score 4):

to display this image, try this.

```
<%= image_tag @image.image_url.to_s if @image.image_url.present? %>
```

Comment: You could use directly `@image.image_url`, there's no need for `"#{@image.image_url}"`